Can I put arbitrary files (not belonging to any target) in a CMake (not file system) folder?
We have a number of files which are not particular to any of the targets (documents containing requirements etc.).
Our build systems include IDEs which support a project tree view that makes it easy to select and display files in the IDE. It would be convenient to have these "global" files show up in this file tree, but not below any target (partly because they logically don't belong there, and partly for convenience).
The usual way to add files to a CMake project is by listing them in the add_executable() or add_library() calls as source files, but these calls define targets and assign the files to them. I tried various set_property() and set_source_files_properties() ideas but none worked. After adding the files to a target, I can put them in a source_group but that creates a folder below the target, which is undesired.
I'm aware that I can create a custom target and simply list "global" files under that target, but that seems like a kludge.
Is there any way to add such "global" files to a CMake project without assigning them to a target, preferably in some CMake folder (by setting the FOLDER property for them)?

so, you want to use CMake to organize your files in a particular way in order to get around your IDE's failings?

@nega No, I want CMake to play my IDE nicely.

Currently I don't think CMake can do what you want without a kludge. A target defined by CMake's add_custom_target() that is a no-op comes to mind. In a POSIX context something like
add_custom_target(extra_docs
                  COMMAND true
                  FOLDER Documentation/Extra
                  SOURCES notes1.txt nonos.rst traps.md do_not_release.html)

wouldn't do anything, but would organize those files under the nested folder "Documentation/Extra" (and without FOLDER, the extra_docs target.)
Unfortunately the FOLDER property only exists for targets, not for files. If you're a VS user, maybe you could abuse the VS_SETTINGS source file property? Depending on how your IDE displays generated source files, you could abuse the GENERATED source file property?
Outside of a kludge I think you'd have the most luck at submitting a feature request at https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake to get the FOLDER property added to source files.

Why so dismissive? Tired? Frustrating work day? ;-) The constraint is in the CMake logic as far as it is known to me (files can only be added to a target which is logically wrong). The various IDEs in principle may or may not be able to show arbitrary files on disk; but what Visual Studio in particular shows in the Solution Explorer is not the file system but an orthogonal structure conceived by the user. In this case this structure is synthesized via CMake. That works pretty well (e.g. using the FOLDER property for targets or source_group for sources, but not in this case.

totally didn't mean to sound dismissive, sorry.

updated my answer, hopefully w/ a better tone
